# android adobe air Remove MovieClip

Tags: android, air, adobe, movieclip

i made a TowerDefens in Flash and would like to use it on my Android phone so i published it as adobe air 3.4 for Android.
And it worked i can play my Game on the Mobile Phone and also the MouseEvents work pretty well on the phone but when it dont remove all the shots that where made as it did on Flash 10.3

The Shots are a MoveClip and i try to remove them from the _root with the Function removeChild(), after i did that i set the Bullet to null, but you can still see it in the screen.

Here's a picture of the wrong part

[image]

The White Points on the Road should be removed

This is the Class of my Bullet if it should be removed.

```
public function removeMe():void{
   this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, eFrame);;
   _root.removeChild(this);
   _root.killMe(this);
   System.gc();
}
```

And the kill this class

```
function killMe(obj:Object):void{
    obj = null;
}
```

If you need moe information ican give the to you, thanks.

// Edit:
The points on the road are blinking.

Comment: Say more about the purpose of the killMe class - it appears to be only nulling a locally passed variable, which is - afaik - going to do nothing.

Comment: On removeMe() I would tend to do it via this.parent.removeChild(this) - is seems most likely that you have another layer between _root and where you are adding the bullet. Like I say above, your killMe() class is meaningless as far as I can see.

Comment: thanks for your comments. I just use the killeMe function because i've read that i have to null the variable so i added the function. I now tried it with the this.parent.removeChild(this) instead of _root.removeChild(this). But the points are still on the road. And i wondering why its only when i publish it for android, if i publish it for the Flashplaye i dont have the problem.

Comment: I think it is a problem with the rendering. I set the bullet to visisble false in the beginning and it worked. But when i set the bullet to visisble false when it should be deleted i have the same issue with when i try to remove it. I traced the steps and it go to the visible false. Do you maybe know how i can improve the rednering ?